# Firebase Auth iOS user Anonymously create but not showing in console

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Suddenly this behaviour started to happen without changing anything. Basically, I'm able to create users Anonymously or even with Email/Password. I get no error whatsoever, actually I'm able to retrieve the userID. However, when I go to the users list in the console, its always empty.

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { user, error in
    self.ifNoError(error) {
        print("Signed In Anonymously \(user?.user.uid)")
    }
}
```

Results:

> Signed In Anonymously Optional("qQazZ3MX8LfQdnlz8F27QDxAT9U2")

[image: Empty List]
[image: Auth Providers Settings]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you looking for in "Authentication"? Check Auth.auth().currentUser

Comment: I'm getting **true** for Auth.auth().currentUser?.isAnonymous and uid is the same as the one shown above

Comment: I just went and disabled Anonymous signIn and it still allowed me to sign in Anonymously?? this is very weird!

Comment: This -> *self.ifNoError(error)* is suspicious and may be providing a false indication that you're actually signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you at any point delete anonymous users from the Firebase console before going live or something like that? That's what I did, not realizing that firebase keeps that user alive on your device...even if you delete the app from the device and re-install. Moreover, it will still work as an accepted anonymous user (even though deleted from the console) UNTIL you force a sign out on a given device. (Oops. TL;DR). Try this.

1. Sign out the user in your app delegate

   `FIRAuth *auth = [FIRAuth auth];
    NSError *error;
    [auth signOut:&error];`
2. Create another anonymous user

   `[auth signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable   authResult, NSError * _Nullable error) {
       NSLog(@"Error is %@", error);
       NSLog(@"Auth result user id is %@", authResult.user.uid);
   }];`

In my case, my device now showed a new user UUID and that user shows up in the Firebase console.

Fun fact: This issue doesn't seem arise with Android. My Android app, which shares the same production firestore, happily created a new user after I deleted the app from the device and reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by creating a manual user email/password (manually on the console), sign in with it through code, delete it thorough code. Then change the code to sign in again Anonymously. This solved the problem!!